# Trying to transfer massive number of data from BigQuery to MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, google-bigquery

I'm trying to transfer a massive number of data from BigQuery to MongoDB.
My BigQuery have 16.5GB of data per day.

Currently, my approach is:

```
bq = bigquery.Client()
query_job = bq.query(sql)
results = query_job.result()

documents = []
for row in results:
  for i in row:
    documents.append(json.loads(i))
```

But this approach causing crash (RAM usage of (70GB)).
So I load this into a list and reload it into a multiprocess into MongoDB.

I'm wondering is there any way of:
1. loading faster?
2. loading while uploading into MongoDB at the same time?

Thanks

Comment: Where the client is running that crashed the memory? You have history data or each new day you generate 16.5GB? Does "at the same time" means online (Near Real Time - NRT)? Please keep in mind that BQ and MongoDB don't have native integration and it could be hard to build an NRT app between them.

Comment: Yes, there are about 16.5GB per day. the crash is happening went downloading 16.5GB into the loop of "documents.append(json.loads(i))", but for now, I have temporary separate into multiple chucks. when reaching a certain threshold, and it starts uploading and clear the list. 

my question is, is there any way to make this part "for row in results:" faster buy using python multiprocessing way? Thanks

Comment: Python docs says [the multiprocessing module allows the programmer to fully leverage multiple processors on a given machine](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html), but not quite sure if it is possible doing the same thing for memory. Regarding the 'loading while uploading' question, do you mean loading data into BigQuery and uploading the same data to MongoDB? If so, it would imply that you read the data from other source, not BQ. Could you clarify?